# How to remove a particular element created dynamically when a dynamically created button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I am trying to make a to-do list.

When a user clicks add after giving input in the text box, a new row is created in a particular table.

This row has the user input as the first column and in the last column, there is a remove button that is dynamically created for every input added by the user.
This button must remove the row it is residing in, to work successfully.

I have tried my best to find the solution but I am having trouble doing so.

Any help is appreciated.

Reference code:

```js
function newTask() {
  //retrieves task from input text box
  var task = document.getElementById('taskInput').value;

  //retrieves everything inside dropdown priority list
  var priorityList = document.getElementById('priorityList');

  //retrieves the index of selected option in dropdown priority list
  var selectedPriorityIndex = priorityList.selectedIndex;

  //retrieves text of selected option from dropdown priority list
  var selectedPriority = priorityList.options[selectedPriorityIndex].text;

  //create a new row
  var Row = document.createElement("tr");

  //adding task to row
  var DataTask = document.createElement("td").appendChild(document.createTextNode(task));
  Row.appendChild(DataTask);

  //adding priority to row
  var DataPriority = document.createElement("td").appendChild(document.createTextNode(selectedPriority));
  Row.appendChild(DataPriority);

  //adding checkbox to row
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkBox");
  var DataCheckBox = document.createElement("td").appendChild(checkBox);
  Row.appendChild(DataCheckBox);

  //add remove button to delete the row
  var removeButton = document.createElement("input");
  removeButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
  removeButton.setAttribute("value", "delete");




  //This is the problem. Idk for sure
  removeButton.onclick = function name(listRow) {
    listRow.remove();
  };




  var DataDeleteButton = document.createElement("td").appendChild(removeButton);
  listRow.appendChild(DataDeleteButton);

  //adding entire row to the table
  document.getElementById("listTable").appendChild(Row);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    To-Do List Tracker
  </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">

    <form>
      <input type="text" class="taskInput" id="taskInput" placeholder="Task">
      <select id="priorityList" class="priorityList">
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" class="addbtn" value="Add" onclick="newTask()">
    </form>

    <div class="listheader">
      <h2>Task List</h1>
    </div>

    <table id="listTable">

    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were basically there. 2 little issues that were preventing the code from working.

In this part:

```
var DataDeleteButton = document.createElement("td").appendChild(removeButton);
  listRow.appendChild(DataDeleteButton);
```

`listRow` is a typo. You had not set up any variable by that name. `Row` was the variable. That's fixed here.

Also, the delete button was not set up right. Event listeners have a single argument `(event)`. You can get the element that the listener is on with `event.target` and you can get the surrounding `<tr>` tag with `event.target.closest('tr')`

```
 removeButton.onclick = function name(e) {
    e.target.closest('tr').remove();
  };
```

While all that got it working, there was one final issue. The way you were creating TD tags and trying to append them didn't work. You cant define the variable and extend it inline with append. So for each of the elements, I changed it like this, so each action was separate

```
var DataDeleteButton = document.createElement("td");
DataDeleteButton.appendChild(removeButton);
Row.appendChild(DataDeleteButton);
```

```js
function newTask() {
  //retrieves task from input text box
  var task = document.getElementById('taskInput').value;

  //retrieves everything inside dropdown priority list
  var priorityList = document.getElementById('priorityList');

  //retrieves the index of selected option in dropdown priority list
  var selectedPriorityIndex = priorityList.selectedIndex;

  //retrieves text of selected option from dropdown priority list
  var selectedPriority = priorityList.options[selectedPriorityIndex].text;

  //create a new row
  var Row = document.createElement("tr");

  //adding task to row
  var DataTask = document.createElement("td")
  DataTask.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task));
  Row.appendChild(DataTask);

  //adding priority to row
  var DataPriority = document.createElement("td");
  DataPriority.appendChild(document.createTextNode(selectedPriority));
  Row.appendChild(DataPriority);

  //adding checkbox to row
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkBox");
  var DataCheckBox = document.createElement("td");
  DataCheckBox.appendChild(checkBox);
  Row.appendChild(DataCheckBox);

  //add remove button to delete the row
  var removeButton =
    document.createElement("input");
  removeButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
  removeButton.setAttribute("value", "delete");

  //This is the problem. Idk for sure
  removeButton.onclick = function name(e) {
    e.target.closest('tr').remove();
  };

  var DataDeleteButton = document.createElement("td");
  DataDeleteButton.appendChild(removeButton);
  Row.appendChild(DataDeleteButton);

  //adding entire row to the table
  document.getElementById("listTable").appendChild(Row);
}
```

```css
#listTable td {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>To-Do List Tracker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <form>
      <input type="text" class="taskInput" id="taskInput" placeholder="Task">
      <select id="priorityList" class="priorityList">
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" class="addbtn" value="Add" onclick="newTask()">
    </form>
    <div class="listheader">
      <h2>Task List</h1>
    </div>
    <table id="listTable">
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `removeButton.onclick = function () { Row.remove(); };` seems to work too.

Comment: Thank you! I can't express my joy, my dopamine levels are out of roof lol. This worked!!

Comment: @Coder123 - no problem. I found a couple other things and added it to my answer. The 'td' tags were not being created but that's fixed now, and I explain why

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information. I made the suggested changes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
removeButton.onclick = function name(listRow) {
        listRow.path[1].remove()
};
```

What I did here is I console.logged the input to your function and find out the way to get into the element that I wanted to remove. Once that's done, work is finished.

Also, there's another error in your code as well.

Change,

```
listRow.appendChild(DataDeleteButton);
```

To

```
Row.appendChild(DataDeleteButton);
```

Hope all is well.

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue with:

```
removeButton.onclick = function name(listRow) {
  listRow.remove();
};
```

is that listRow is declared in the argument list, so it's not the same thing as listRow from the newTask function. It can be fixed just by removing listRow from the argument list. (And consistently naming the thing Row or listRow). e.g.:

```
removeButton.onclick = function name() {
  listRow.remove();
};
```